# How to make a 301 redirect rule for old AMP pages?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, amp-html

My website was on an old AMP plugin which added `/amp/` after every post/page URL.

So my home for example is: `https://example.com` and the "amp" one was `https://example.com/amp/`.

I wanted to know what rule can I put in the `.htaccess` file to make a redirect of all these `/amp/` URLs to the "normal" page itself.

So for example: `https://example.com/my-article-1/amp/` redirects to `https://example.com/my-article-1/`, `https://example.com/my-article-2/` redirects to `https://example.com/my-article-2/` and it does for every article/page.

I'm sure it's possible to do it without typing 1000 lines of 301 "easy" redirects in `.htaccess`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay fellas,

I found the solution, this is the Redirect Rule you need to put to say goodbye to /amp/:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/amp(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,L]
```

I hope it will be helpful

Comment: This won't redirect the homepage, ie. `example.com/amp/`. It will also potentially match/remove too much, since it removes the part of the URL-path from `/amp` to the end of the URL-path. eg. `/foo/amplitude` and `/foo/amphetamine` would both be redirected to `/foo/`. The _condition_ (`RewriteCond` directive) is also unnecessary as this can be achieved using a single directive. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76784079/369434) below that addresses these issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a single mod_rewrite directive at the top of the root `.htaccess` file (no need for a separate *condition*):

```
RewriteEngine On

# Removes "amp" (or "amp/") from the end of the URL-path
RewriteRule (.*)amp/?$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

This redirects `example.com/amp` to `example.com/` and `example.com/article/amp/` to `example.com/article/`. But URLs like `example.com/amplitude` are untouched.